# When I change pointers in linked list, does the original still hold or does it get removed automatically?

Tags: python, linked-list

I have a very basic question about linked list

say I reverse the following linked list:

`#1->2->3->4`   to become `4->3->2->1`

And say I start first with reversing the pointer that points from 1 to 2; so that 2 points to 1. My question is, does the pointer/connection from 1 to 2 still exist when I do this?

Or does this connection get removed when we do 2->1?

A further question if the above is true, is "does the original connection 1->2->3->4 always hold, no matter what we do to the pointers; or does it get removed, if say I changed the pointer at 1 to point at 3; i.e. 1->3 ; then does the connection 1->2 gets removed automatically?

Comment: It all depends on how you implement link list.
In the most common single link list when you change pointer, the previous one is no longer available

Comment: The Python built in list, initialized as `list()` or `[]` is implemented over an underlying array that can be re-allocated, not over a linked list with pointers. If you are refering to another specific implementation of an actual linked list, please cite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a node in a linked list has a single reference to another node: the next one.

When you have a list with 4 nodes, you can visualise it like this:

```
 head
  ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │   │ data: 4  │
│ next: —————→ │ next: —————→ │ next: —————→ │ next:None│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

You ask:

> And say I start first with reversing the pointer that points from 1 to 2; so that 2 points to 1. My question is, does the pointer/connection from 1 to 2 still exist when I do this?

"reversing the pointer" is not really the right way to express what happens. The "pointer" that points from 1 to 2 will be set to `None`, and *another* reference will be set to point from 2 to 1. It is not the same one!

So first the `next` reference in the first node is made to refer to the node that precedes it -- but as there is no such node it gets to be `None`:

```
 head
  ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │   │ data: 4  │
│ next:None│   │ next: —————→ │ next: —————→ │ next:None│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

And then the same happens with the second node. Its `next` reference is made to refer to the first node:

```
 head
  ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │   │ data: 4  │
│ next:None│ ←———— :next  │   │ next: —————→ │ next:None│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

### A bit more about the typical reversal algorithm

As an additional step the `head` reference should be made to point to what now has become the start of the part that is already reversed:

```
                head
                 ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │   │ data: 4  │
│ next:None│ ←———— :next  │   │ next: —————→ │ next:None│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

At each step in this reversal, there is a disconnection between the node whose `next` is altered, and the node that originally followed it (in the last visualisation, the node with value 3 cannot be reached any more from the node that is pictured at its left side).

For this reason you need to have a variable to remember what the original next node was, so that you can proceed and also change *that* node's `next` attribute. You could call that variable `next`:

```
                head           next
                 ↓              ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │   │ data: 4  │
│ next:None│ ←———— :next  │   │ next: —————→ │ next:None│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

If we proceed with the next step, the following actions are performed:

We copy the reference of `next`... maybe in a variable called `current`:

```
                               current
                head           next
                 ↓              ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │   │ data: 4  │
│ next:None│ ←———— :next  │   │ next: —————→ │ next:None│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

Then remember what the original next node was, by referring to it with the variable `next`:

```
                head           current        next
                 ↓              ↓              ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │   │ data: 4  │
│ next:None│ ←———— :next  │   │ next: —————→ │ next:None│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

Then change the reference from 3 to 4 to a reference from 3 to 2:

```
                head           current        next
                 ↓              ↓              ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │   │ data: 4  │
│ next:None│ ←———— :next  │ ←———— :next  │   │ next:None│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

Note that now the right most node is detached. We still need to update the `head` reference:

```
                               head
                               current        next
                                ↓              ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │   │ data: 4  │
│ next:None│ ←———— :next  │ ←———— :next  │   │ next:None│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

Now only one cycle remains that starts by setting the `current` reference... etc.

See also [How does this recursive function to reverse a linked list work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67399657/5459839)

Comment: Thanks Trincot, you're a life saver! it is so clear now